# Impersonating an ASP.net session with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, session, curl

I'm trying to retrieve data from a publicly accessible website that is built on ASP.net sessions. When I send standard browser headers with PHP curl, I keep getting the error that the session has expired. How can I impersonate a session with curl or some other PHP function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[curl_septopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Using the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE allows you to capture and re-use the site's cookies to manipulate the session.  Check the doc page for more info.

Comment: thanks matt, I just passed the ASPnet_sessionId cookie with those options and it worked fine.